# Rails has_many self referential

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have an accounts model as follows (simplified):

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :account_number, :display_name, :master_account_id

    has_many :child_accounts, :class_name => "Account", :foreign_key => "id"
    belongs_to :master_account, :class_name => "Account", :foreign_key => "master_account_id"
end
```

`@account.master_account` is currently working correctly, but I also want to be able to access `@account.child_accounts` - what do I need to do in order to fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it has to be the other way round:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child_accounts, :class_name => "Account", :foreign_key => "master_account_id"
  belongs_to :master_account, :class_name => "Account"
end
```

Comment: Indeed it was the case. After reading it over a few times while keeping in mind the rails magic it started to make sense;

belongs_to automatically looks for the symbol that follows it + _id in the current model, and uses that as its own foreign key, hence I didn't need to specify it explicitly like I was attempting.

has_many didn't know that the foreign key pointing to it was "master_account_id" so it needed to be explicitly told that, so that the reverse lookup could also work.

Comment: What roots should be written for this kind of association , if I want something like ->  master_account/1/child_account/2

Comment: @vishB roots = routes. You could define two nested resources and point both to an `AccountsController`. Ask a separate question if this is unclear.