# has_many, belongs_to circular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a model `ApiKey`

```
class ApiKey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :third_party_api_keys #points to other Apikeys
  belongs_to :origin_key #points to another ApiKey
end
```

I want it to have associations to other api keys. I cannot find how to set this up so I may be approaching this wrong. Do I need a join model? and do a `:through`

Comment: So you want the `ApiKey` model to have an association with another instance of the `ApiKey` model?

Comment: @jkeuhlen that is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this for recursive associations:

```
belongs_to :origin_key, class_name: 'ApiKey'
has_many :third_party_api_keys, class_name: 'ApiKey', foreign_key: :origin_key_id
```

If you need to optimize your selects, you can also use a gem like [closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) so you can 
get all the hierarchy of an element with a single select.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) that handles your exact question and I would recommend starting there.

In addition check out this [other stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100091/rails-has-many-self-referential) question that answers your own.

There are also the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) which describe how to do a self join.

To solve your problem you will want to do something like

```
class ApiKey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :third_party_api_keys, class_name: 'Keys', foreign_key: :origin_key_id
  belongs_to :origin_key, class_name: 'Keys'
end
```

Because this is a self referential join, you won't need another join table, just an origin_key_id in the ApiKey table.